# Unable to debug SPListEventReceiver

Tags: event-receivers, visual-studio-2012, debugging

Running VS and SharePoint on the same server, but I am unable to debug my simple `Event Receiver` to see why it is not firing.

Here is the snipp:

```
public class EventReceiver1 : SPListEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A list was added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ListAdded(properties);

        TestReceiver(properties.WebUrl, properties.ListId);
    }

    protected TestReceiver(string webUrl, Guid listGuid)
    {
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
        {
            using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[listGuid];
                list.Description = "Test";
                list.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution deploys successfully, but going back to the UI and adding a list, description is not updated as seen in the `TestReceiver()` method. Attempting to attach VS to all `w3wp` process does not load any breakpoints either. What gives?

**EDIT**

I have also confirmed via Powershell, that the document library does have my `Event Receiver` attached to it.

Comment: are you using sp2010 w/ .NET 3.5?

Comment: @Colbs SP2013 w/ .NET 4.5

Comment: Have you ever gotten it to break? Like on the first deploy maybe?

Comment: @Colbs no not once to my recollection. To be honest, I don't even think the ER is firing. I added a `try-catch` to reach out and log to a DB, but nothing has been logged and the description of the list is never updated.

Comment: hmm, worked for me using ListAdding. Can you update the description in that event?

Comment: Yup, just confirmed - ListAdded doesn't break but ListAdding does.. weird

Comment: @Colbs just tried to use ListAdding, doesn't look like it gets called either. I'm so confused. Never had difficulty like this with ERs before.

Comment: I know, so strange. I'll do some more research but this is the first time I've used that Event override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-deploying event receivers will sometimes continue to point to an old version. You may have tried some of these but here's how I would troubleshoot:

1. Download [SP Manager](https://spm.codeplex.com/) and drill down to the List where the Event
   Receiver is attached. You can remove / delete it manually.

   - use Powershell to remove the Event Rece3vier
   - Make sure you are attaching all W3WP Processes (From all Users)
   - Manually deploy the .dll to the GAC
   - Do a Full Retract / Install w/ Powershell (not VS)
   - IIS Reset
   - If all that fails, create a new list and new Event Receiver

Comment: A couple questions. **Manually deploy the .dll...** are you talking about physically dropping the .dll into the GAC or the old school stsadm way? **Do a full Retract/Install...** Are the Deploy/Retract options given through VS not sufficient for development of ERs?

Comment: You may have to use GACUtil.exe or manually navigate to GAC_MSIL to delete it. On rare occasions, Powershell will deploy things that VS cannot

Comment: I had tried all still Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
protected void TestReceiver(string webUrl, Guid listGuid)
```

instead of

```
protected TestReceiver(string webUrl, Guid listGuid)
```